# How to disassociate CloudFront distribution from alias sub-domain?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We have the following scenario:

1. We are using S3 and CloudFront.
2. An engineer has created an `S3` bucket and `CloudFront Distribution` under their personal account.
3. They then associated the CloudFront to a sub-domain owned by the company.
4. They left the company.

This is obviously an unacceptable practice and is probably one of the reasons this engineer is no longer working for the company. Unfortunately, we now have to sort it out.

Now to the issue at hand.

We've created a new S3 bucket and `CloudFront` distribution. But as you'd expect, we are unable to associate the new distribution ID with the same sub-domain and are getting the following error:

```
CNAMEAlreadyExists: One of more of the CNAMEs you provided are already associated with a different resource
```

We have already tracked down the conflicting CF distribution id:

```
$ aws-vault exec corp-dev -- aws cloudfront list-conflicting-aliases --alias dev.local.domain --distribution-id XYZ
{
    "ConflictingAliasesList": {
        "MaxItems": 100,
        "Quantity": 1,
        "Items": [
            {
                "Alias": "dev.local.domain",
                "DistributionId": "******ECHOHUO",
                "AccountId": "******000000"
            }
        ]
    }
}

$ aws-vault exec corp-dev -- aws cloudfront associate-alias --target-distribution-id NEW_Distribution_id --alias dev.local.domain

An error occurred (IllegalUpdate) when calling the AssociateAlias operation: Alias move is not allowed since the source distribution is enabled.
```

However, it is not entirely clear how to disassociate the subdomain from that distribution ID. The company owns the domain and Route53.

Do we need to involve AWS support for this or is there a non-obvious way to force the disassociation, so the subdomain(s) can be re-used again?

Answer (score 0):

For anybody who might be landing on this issue with the same question here's the answer:

1. Be sure to check **all** resources which can allocate CNAMEs (i.e. cf distribution, AWS Amplify, etc).
2. If you can't find the resource then contact `AWS Support` -- they will be able to validate if the CNAME is allocated by our own resources or by another account id.

In our case, it turned out to be a CNAME resource under our control. The error above was showing a completely different account id which is why we got confused and thought the resource was actually under a personal account.

Comment: What created the CNAME in your case? I'm seeing the exact same issue but have no idea where the CNAME is registered. Can't see anything in Route 53 or CloudFront.

Comment: In our case it was a AWS CodeBuild and AWS Amplify that had automatically configured resources.

Comment: I ended up having to buy a support plan and opening a ticket. Straight away they were able to tell me there was an API Gateway with the registered apex domain. Once I deleted that, I could and the domain  to the CF distribution and the A record in Route 53. Adding the TXT record did nothing. Why they can't add a proper error telling you where the domain is registered is beyond me when they clearly have the tools. Horrible developer experience.

Comment: Yeah, we also needed to buy the support plan. At least your case was resolved fast. We had multiple sub-accounts and we had to purchase support for each to "confirm inter-account-access"... :D